# Why is my new iMac so slow with Jupiter notebooks?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I recently purchased a new (2020 version) iMac 27" with a 16gb ram. I had the exact same computer but an older version (2017) that am upgrading from.

I was very surprised to see that running the exact same code on both machines, with the latest version of Jupyter/ python, the newer iMac is about three times slower than my old one!

I mean that quite literally, as I can run the same code on my old computer three times before the new one finishes, so I don't believe it is a memory issue.

After hours of research, I am stumped as to way this is happening. It is brand new, and the only app on there is Anaconda. Any advice on how I could boost the speed to run code on my newer computer?

Thank you

Comment: Cross-posted [here at the Jupyter Community discourse forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/new-imac-27-is-extremely-slow-when-running-code/16088?u=fomightez). In the future, if you are going to cross-post, post the links to the other posts with your question. (In this case, it was probably more appropriate here.) Otherwise, you cost more people time saying the same thing, or it can result in others following in your footsteps to not find the solution because it's on one site and not the other. Keep in mind 'others following in your footsteps' may be a future version of yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the M1 optimized build for conda?

https://www.anaconda.com/blog/new-release-anaconda-distribution-now-supporting-m1

Comment: Thank you for the response! I did the 2022.05 update and unfortunately there are so no improvements. Any other ideas?

Comment: can you run this? 

import platform; platform.architecture()

Comment: Yes, it comes back with ('64bit', '')

Comment: sorry run platform.platform() in your conda env. It should come back with arm64 (if it does, I apologize and I'm not sure why it's slow for you)

Comment: It comes back with 'macOS-10.16-x86_64-i386-64bit'. Is that the issue?

Comment: All right you're not running the m1 version of python and it's going through rosetta translation. But yes, that's the issue. you need the ARM compatible python for whatever kernel you're using

Comment: It looks like I actually don't have an m1 processor, but the i7 core.

Comment: Ah, sorry I was making an incorrect assumption. Normally when  assumed that a mac was slow it was usually due to Rosetta. Can you run benchmarks on your new vs. old machines?